# What am I missing. The compiler says that & needs an L value for this line:

Tags: linked-list

I'm trying to merge two sorted linked lists into one linked list

start with the ListNode structure

```
        struct ListNode
        {
            int val;
            ListNode* next;
            
            ListNode(): val(0), next(nullptr){}
            ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
            ListNode(int x, ListNode* next) : val(x), next(next) {}
        };
```

This is the code fragment that contains the problem line
int temp;
ListNoded* currR;

this is the offending line. The compiler says I need an 'L' value
currR->next = &ListNode();

```
    //What am I missing?
```

Comment: It will help you get an answer if you add the tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Looks like a typo.  If it's not, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. Those are constructors that run when I execute the "new" operator. I have to do something like ListNode* list1 = new struct ListNode();
That compiles and runs.